# AWS GameLift: Error! Cannot edit fleet. Launch path must begin with '/local/game'

Tags: amazon-web-services, unity-game-engine, aws-sdk, amazon-gamelift

After I create a fleet in GameLift, try to edit it, then click on submit, I get this error:

> Error! Cannot edit fleet TestFleet. Reason: Update of fleet launch
>   configuration failed : Launch path must begin with '/local/game'..

This is weird because even if I do not change anything, but click on submit, I still get this error. Also, '/local/game' is added automatically to the game path, but I still get the error.

[Current script path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFhZc.png)

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The only way I was able to fix it was to delete that fleet and make a new one. Not an ideal solution at all.

I feel it's a bug in the GameLift console as there are many others (some tooltips don't work, you have to switch back and forth between pages for things to update sometimes, prompt windows don't always respond, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

With `C:\local\game` in your path, it's probably a **Windows 2012** instance but you're trying to add `/local/game/` to it.  It should be `C:\game\RealtimeScript.js`.

If it's a **Amazon Linux** instance, your path should read `/local/game/RealtimeScript.js`.